# Using Python multiprocessing.Process inside a Docker Container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, multiprocessing

The code below works when being run as a regular Python process. Calling `start` starts a new process.
When I run the same code inside a docker container, the method `my_function` never gets called.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def my_function(x, y):
    print("process started")


def start():
    p = Process(target=my_function, args=(1, 2))
    p.start()
```

The `Dockerfile` has `FROM python:3.8-slim-buster`.
Is there some configuration needed on the Docker side to enable the multiprocessing?

Comment: How do you run the Python code?

Comment: If you're just not seeing the `print` statement, setting the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` or giving the `python -u` option might help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
def start():
    p = Process(target=my_function, args=(1, 2))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the Dockerfile in a valid format. Your code worked with my valid Dockerfile and printed `process started` as expected.

You can compare with the following the example of both Dockerfile and the python script file (prints the process id to validate) below..

Example below:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ADD multiprocess_test.py /
CMD [ "python", "./multiprocess_test.py" ]
```

I have the following codes, in `multiprocess_test.py` [source: official documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class):

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Now, do `docker build -t mp-test .` and then `docker run --rm -it  mp-test:latest`, the result would be like

```
main line
module name: __main__
parent process: 0
process id: 1
function f
module name: __main__
parent process: 1
process id: 6
hello bob
```